# How do I update 2 columns from one table (Source) with another table (Target)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a source table called Edwin.psp_labor_schd_day_f_rollup_frs_356 and a target table called EDWIN.PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP, I need to update the date values from source to target. The 2 date columns are SRC_CREATED_DATE and SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE. Based on the following on clause

```
  A.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY = B.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY AND
  A.AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY    = B.AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY AND
  A.AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY = B.AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY AND
  A.SCHEDULE_LINE_ID         = B.SCHEDULE_LINE_ID
```

How can this be done?

The Merge code which we are using

```
MERGE
/*+ parallel(A) enable_parallel_dml*/
INTO
(
  SELECT
    PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY,
    AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY,
    AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY,
    SCHEDULE_LINE_ID,
    SRC_CREATED_DATE,
    SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
  FROM
    EDWFIN.PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP
)
A USING
(
  SELECT
    pay_range_start_date_key,
    aa_person_natural_key,
    aa_person_assignment_key,
    schedule_line_id,
    MAX(src_created_date) src_created_date,
    MAX(src_last_update_date) src_last_update_date
  FROM
    edwfin.psp_labor_schd_day_f_rollup_frs_356
  GROUP BY
    pay_range_start_date_key,
    aa_person_natural_key,
    aa_person_assignment_key,
    schedule_line_id
)
B ON
(
  A.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY = B.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY AND
  A.AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY    = B.AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY AND
  A.AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY = B.AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY AND
  A.SCHEDULE_LINE_ID         = B.SCHEDULE_LINE_ID
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET
    A.SRC_CREATED_DATE     = B.SRC_CREATED_DATE,
    A.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE = B.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
  WHERE
    A.SRC_CREATED_DATE      <> B.SRC_CREATED_DATE
  OR A.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE <> B.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE;
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked into JOINs?

Comment: I have used merge earlier but the main problem is merging throws I get the same "ORA-30926 " error, but the business wants even the duplicate data also to be updated, hence thought update does the process row by row unlike merge and can update the same set of row twice again hence wanted to test with Update statement

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  If you have existing code, you shuld show it.

Comment: If you're getting an `ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables` error because there are multiple rows in the source table for a single row in the target table, how do you know which of the two values to use for the update?  If you solve that, you can fix your `merge` issue.  If you don't fix it, your `update` will likely run into an issue where a single-row subquery returns multiple rows.

Comment: Please read and heed https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have updated the ticket with the merge code which we are using for the update.